# embedded ruby syntax "<%= .. %>" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Am I correct with the idea below regarding ERB template? any advice would be really appreciated.

Is the embedded ruby syntax with an equal sign "<%= %>" intended to render some output? while the one without the equal sign "<% %>" doesn't.

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby

Answer (score 6):

When you use `<%= %>` you render the expression value to your output. While `<% %>` is simply to write some **Ruby** code that won't be rendered to final output.